# HTML5 Offline not working in Opera Mobile(with Turbo ON) & Web SQL not working with Turbo OFF

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, html, jquery-mobile, opera-mobile

I'm using MVC architecture for my html5 + jQuery mobile application. I'm facing a problem in opera mobile 12(When Turbo ON), when I try to do application cache(manifest) for saving pages for offline use. But when I switch OFF turbo, offline cache is working fine but not HTLM5 Storage (LocalStorage & Web SQL). I need Offline Cache & Storages to run in my application. I tested my application in Safari, Chrome & Android's default browser and it is working properly.

Can anybody help me to figure out this issue? I would really appreciate any help on this.